# Proof for continuity: $f (x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\ 0 & \, (x,y)=(0,0) \\ \end{array} \right. $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have to prove the continuity of the following function:

$f (x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
0 & \, (x,y)=(0,0) \\
\end{array}
\right. $

**Case 1:** $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ is obviously continuous

**Case 2:** $(x,y)=(0,0)$, use $\epsilon$-$\delta$-criteria

$|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|=|f(x,y)|=|\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}|=\frac{|2xy|}{x^2+y^2}\leq2|xy|$

Look at a $\delta$-environment of $(0,0)$

$|(x,y)-(0,0)|<\delta \Rightarrow x^2+y^2<\delta^2$

$|x|<\delta, |y|<\delta \Rightarrow |xy|<\delta^2$, from where we can see

$|f(x,y)|\leq 2|xy|<2\delta^2\leq\epsilon^2 \Rightarrow \delta < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}$

Therefore the function has to be continuous for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$

**My question is:**
Is the proof right and what can I improve in the clarity of my proof?

Comment: How do you get $|f(x,y)|\le 2|xy|$??

Comment: You can probably find several post on this site about continuity of this (or a very similar) function, such as [Show discontinuity of $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/572125) or [Prove that $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ is not continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2293636) If you are mainly asking about checking your own attempt - as opposed to finding any solution of the problem - you should add the ([tag:proof-verification]) tag (see the [tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-verification/info).)

Answer (score 4):

The function is not continuous at $(0,0).$ Note that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,\lambda x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{2\lambda x^2}{(1+\lambda^2)x^2}=\dfrac{2\lambda}{1+\lambda^2}.$$

You use the inequality $|f(x,y)|\le 2|xy|$ but note that:

$$\frac{2|xy|}{x^2+y^2}=|f(x,y)|\leq 2|xy|\iff x^2+y^2\ge 1.$$ Since you are working on a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ such inequality is not valid.

Comment: Mh, what should I get from that "note"?

Comment: If you refer to the first one you should get that the limit depends on the way the function approaches to $(0,0).$ If you refer to the second one you should get that the inequality doesn't hold. Indeed, it is $|f(x,y)|>2|xy|$ if $x^2+y^2<1$ and $(x,y)\ne (0,0).$